# Trying to make an image large in wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Okay, so for the record I do not code at all but I have been trying to make minor changes to a website's css and html in Wordpress (it's a theme I'm trying to tweak just to be clear).

All was going well till I tried to add a banner image to my website. Long story short after trying to add some new html and css to obtain the result that I was after I found what I thought was a better route - using an already existing function in the theme to insert my image. Now I just need some help figuring out how to resize it to fit the screen.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5kgx.jpg) is a print screen image of what the home page currently looks like

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAV4u.jpg) is an example of what I would like the ultimate result to be

And here is the code that currently pertains to the current image:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    <div class="site-branding">
        <a href="http://www.eboniequill.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="1000" height="333" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?fit=1000%2C333" class="custom-logo" alt="Ebonie Quill" itemprop="logo" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?w=1000 1000w, https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?resize=300%2C100 300w, https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?resize=768%2C256 768w, https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?resize=450%2C150 450w, https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?resize=850%2C283 850w" sizes="(max-width: 739px) 94vw, (max-width: 969px) 88vw, (max-width: 1199px) 860px, 850px" data-attachment-id="148" data-permalink="http://www.eboniequill.com/cropped-twitter-cover-ebonie-quill-png/" data-orig-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?fit=1000%2C333" data-orig-size="1000,333" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png" data-image-description="<p>http://www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png</p>
"data-medium-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?fit=300%2C100" data-large-file="https://i0.wp.com/www.eboniequill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cropped-Twitter-Cover-Ebonie-Quill.png?fit=850%2C283"></a>
        <div class="site-title" style="opacity: 1;">
        <a href="http://www.eboniequill.com/" rel="home">
            <span style="display: none;">Ebonie Quill</span>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 761 101" style="width: 761px;">
                <text x="50%" y="0.82em" stroke="#fff" text-anchor="middle" stroke-width="3" font-size="119">
                    Ebonie Quill
                </text>
            </svg></a>

        </div>

            <p class="site-description" style="color: rgb(184, 182, 183);">
                <span class="site-description-text">Connecting Cultures Through Diversity</span>
                <span class="site-description-after" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; opacity: 1;"></span>
            </p>

                </div><!-- .site-branding -->

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="button-toggle  js-nav-trigger" aria-controls="menu-primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="nav-icon icon--lines"></span>
            <span class="button-text  assistive-text">Primary Menu</span>
        </button>
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="nav nav--main js-nav--main" aria-hidden="false" style="border-top-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);"><li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-19" style="opacity: 1;"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-62" aria-haspopup="true" style="opacity:1;">ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/category/archaeology/">Archaeology</a><ul class="sub-menu" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
<li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-post_tag menu-item-66"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/tag/dinosaurs/" tabindex="-1">Dinosaurs</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-63" style="opacity: 1;"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/category/anthropology/">Anthropology</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-65" style="opacity: 1;"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/category/psychology/" tabindex="0">Psychology</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-67" style="opacity: 1;"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/category/travel/" tabindex="0">Travel</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" style="opacity: 1;"><ahref="http://www.eboniequill.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="nav--toolbar--left_wrapper" style="opacity: 1;"><ul id="menu-social-media-left" class="nav  nav--toolbar  nav--toolbar--left"><li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-74"><a href="https://www.patreon.com/eboniequill">Support Us on Patreon</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="nav--toolbar--right_wrapper" style="opacity: 1;"><ul id="menu-social-menu" class="nav  nav--toolbar  nav--toolbar--right  right"><li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-68"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/eboniequill">Facebook</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-69"><ahref="https://twitter.com/ebonie_quill">Twitter</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-70"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/eboniequill/">Pinterest</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-72"><a href="https://eboniequill.tumblr.com">Tumblr</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-73"><ahref="https://www.bloglovin.com/@eboniequill">Blog Lovin’</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="nav-dropdown_wrapper" style="opacity: 1;"></li></ul>
<ahref="#search" class="button-toggle  button-toggle--search">
            <span class="button-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            <span class="button-text  assistive-text">Search</span>
        </a>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Could someone please tell me what I should change in the html or css to make the changes I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet we can execute to see the current state of your work ?

Comment: I think I managed to give you an executable snippet - if I haven't managed to give you what you needed just let me know :) Thanks!

Comment: Okay! I managed to fix it by playing around with the css sheets while still keeping the image responsive :) yayy